# Editing Wordpress Widget CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

I'm working on my school newspaper's wordpress website, and I'm trying to indent the content of the rotating tweets widget by 15px.  I've tried adding the following code to the wordpress theme editor's style.css sheet, but it hasn't made any noticeable changes:

```
.rotatingtweet{padding-left: 15px;}
```

When I add the same line of code in google Chrome in developer mode, it has the desired effect, but I just can't get it to work by editing the website's main style.css file in the "Voice" wordpress theme.

Thanks for your time!
-John

Comment: Do you have a link to share?

Comment: It's at coa.menloschool.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tweets are displayed with `position: absolute` within their container, so they ignore the padding.

Put the padding on the outer div instead, then adjust the header:

```
.widget_rotatingtweets_widget {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.widget_rotatingtweets_widget h4 {
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

EDIT: The above, with additional tweaks to borders and such, will work, but there may be a slightly easier solution.

Instead of using padding, give the rotating tweets container a left margin. In your style.css file (probably line 102), there is a selector:

```
#content .rotatingtweets,
#content .norotatingtweets  {
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
```

If you change this to:

```
#content .rotatingtweets,
#content .norotatingtweets  {
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

and move the borders to the elements just before and after the rotatingtweets container:

```
.sidebar .widget_rotating_tweets .widget_title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}
.widget_rotating_tweets .follow-button {
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

This seems to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much bobdye!  That did the trick...I spent a few hours trying to get this to work yesterday, so you just saved me a lot of time!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where my css properties on the main style sheets were being overridden...was the container for the rotating tweets widget included in the html after the main css stylesheet, or does position take precedence over padding?  (I'm a CSS noob...just trying to figure out what I was doing wrong :)

Comment: After implementing your code snippet, it looks like the background of the box etc is shifted (which makes sense).  Is there a way to override the position:absolute property in the tweets container from the outside?  I tried using `.rotatingtweet{ position: relative; left: 15px;}` in style.css but didn't notice any changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately I am unable to find this rotating tweets container in the main style.css file that I can edit using the wordpress theme editor: http://coa.menloschool.org/wp-content/themes/voice/style.css?ver=1.2.1  Do you know the location of the style.css file you were talking about, and how I can edit the wordpress files other than the Voice theme's style.css?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately I am unable to find this rotating tweets container in the main style.css file that I can edit using the wordpress theme editor: http://coa.menloschool.org/wp-content/themes/voice/style.css?ver=1.2.1

Comment: Two more questions that I've had trouble answering as a CSS noob, even with the help of all-knowing google: what is the difference between referring to a container with `.container` or `#container`?  Could `.sidebar` also be referred to as `#sidebar`, for instance?  Also, do we need to include the entire hierarchy of containers when referring to classes?  For example, is `.sidebar .widget_rotating_tweets .widget_title` the same as `.sidebar .widget_title`, in the case that there is only one widget in the sidebar container?  Thanks so much for you help! :)

Comment: '.sidebar' is an element with class 'sidebar', '#sidebar' is an element with ID 'sidebar'. Each CSS selector has what is called 'specificity'. If there are multiple selectors for the same element, the one with more specificity wins. So, for example, if you have .widget_title ( padding: 10px; } and .sidebar .widget_title { padding: 20px; }, then the padding will be 20px because the second selector is more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation bobdye!  That makes a lot of sense.  My changes in style.css are still being overriden by the widgets' respective css files, unfortunately.  Do you know if I'm